# How to document as parameter default value

Tags: javascript

I just want know why，please anybody give give me some hint?

```js
const getElement = (selector, scope = window.document) => scope.querySelector(selector);

const getElement = (selector, scope) => (scope || window.document).querySelector(selector);
```

will catch error `querySelector is not a function` when called it in `DOMContentLoaded` block. Object `window` should already exist.

```js
// document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  // const $table = getElement("table");
  const $table = document.querySelector("table");

  // const $trees = getElement("[data-tree]", $table);
  const $trees = getElement("[data-tree]");
});
```

```js
const getElement = (selector, scope = window.document) => scope.querySelector(selector);

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {

  let aa = getElement('[data-tree]')

  console.log( aa.textContent )

  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row         { background-color: yellow; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```

```html
<div   data-tree="xyz" >hello world</div>
```

Comment: Are they both getting the same error?

Comment: @HaoWu Yes, very time.

Comment: How do you made your `DOMContentLoaded` block ? ( I have no error )

Comment: @MisterJojo yes, i'm tried both with `DOMContentLoaded` & `turbolinks:load` block. Perhaps the turbolinks cache caused it? I'm going to check it right now

Comment: `Turbolinks is no longer under active development` https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes, you are right. Thank your tips, but i need it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default param wont work when you pass `null` there ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)), but `null || value` will fall to `value`

> Default function parameters allow named parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

```js
const defaultTest = (val = 'abc') => {
  console.log('val:', val)
  console.log('val:', val || 'abc')
}

defaultTest(null)
defaultTest()
```

Comment: will print `undefinded` when i updated `console.log('val:', val || 'cba')` after calls `defaultTest()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `window.onload()` event since it waits for all content on your page to be loaded. It might be the selector is not ready in DOM.